# C# не понимает GetCurrentDomain ()

Tags: c#

Делаю программу которая для начала будет выводить имя домена в котором находится комп, как я понял нужно через

`public static System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain GetCurrentDomain ();`
хотя куда это сувать я так и не понял, компилятор ругается и кричит, как устранить эту странную ошибку или получить имя домена?

```
'MainWindow.GetCurrentDomain()" должен объявлять тело, так как он не помечен модификатором abstract, extern или partial.
```

Comment: Удостоверьтесь, что к вашему проекту подключена сборка System.DirectoryServices.dll

Comment: Сейчас подключена

Comment: Тогда ответ данный ниже должен работать и вызов `var domainName = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetCurrentDomain();` должен возвращать нужные данные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем проекте нет ссылки на соответствующую сборку.

Решение проблемы:

1. Добавить ссылку на сборку. Для этого в *Обозревателе решений* правой
   клавишей мыши щелкаете по проекту - Добавить - Ссылку. В появившемся
   окне в строке поиска вводите `System.DirectoryServices` и ставите
   галочку напротив первого результата.
2. В файле исходного кода добавляете:

   ```
   using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
   ```
3. Теперь в коде можете вызывать метод:

   ```
   var domainName = Domain.GetCurrentDomain().Name;
   ```